# issue with Firebase Auth

Tags: firebase

I started a project using firebase a month ago, left it in working condition. I've opened it up again to begin working on it and have been hit with errors all from Firebase.

> The error is Use of unresolved identifier 'Auth'

I have tried updating pods, clean the project and rebuilding.

I don't know what else to do, I have tried checking if the Firebase has been updated, it hasn't, the documentation is still the same.

[Image of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ObCZg.jpg)

Comment: Can you show the screenshot where it says that .

Comment: Remember to open the project with the .workspace document, not the .xcodeproj document.

Comment: @SouravSachdeva I have added an image to your convenience. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had fixed the error by updating the pods to 4.x, pods were currently installing version 3 of firebase, I had to manually remove the 'Firebase' from the podfile, update the repo and then add the 'Firebase' pods again. Not entirely sure why **pod update** was not updating it to latest version.